# Event Hub input binding for Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure Function with an input binding to an Event Hub.

```
public static async Task Run(TraceWriter log, string eventHubMessage)
```

When the function is triggered, how many messages does it receive per execution by default?

Is it 1 execution = 1 message?

I have read the documentation and understand you can set these properties in the function's host.json file:

```
"eventHub": {
  // The maximum event count received per receive loop. The default is 64.
  "maxBatchSize": 64,
  // The default PrefetchCount that will be used by the underlying EventProcessorHost.
  "prefetchCount": 256
}
```

Does maxBatchSize mean I will receive 64 messages in 1 execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mikhail is correct.  I'd just like to add the following:

1. If you use the default EventHub-Trigger C# template, the Function created will process 1 message per execution.

2. If you need each execution to process in batches, change the following:

   a. In `function.json`, add the property `"cardinality":"many"` as shown [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-templates/blob/dev/Templates/EventHubTrigger-JavaScript/function.json).

   b. In `run.csx`, modify Function signature and process messages in a loop, e.g.,

   `public static async Task Run(TraceWriter log, string[] eventHubMessages)
   {
     foreach(string message in eventHubMessages)
     {
       // process messages
     }
   }`
3. The host.json configuration you specified in the question allows you to experiment with the correct batch size and prefetch buffer to meet the needs of your workflow.

**Additional comments:**

1. Under the Consumption Plan, a Function is currently allowed a <strike>max</strike> default 5-minute execution time **(configurable up to 10 mins --Added on 11/30/2017)**.  You should experiment with the *maxBatchSize* and *prefetchCount* setting to ensure that a typical execution of the batch will complete within the timeframe.

2. The *prefetchCount* should be 3-4 times the *maxBatchSize*.

3. Each Function host instance is backed by a single EventProcessorHost (EPH).  EPH uses a checkpointing mechanism to mark the last successfully processed message.  A Function execution could terminate prematurely due to <s>uncaught exceptions in the Function code</s> host crashing, timeout or partition lease lost, resulting in an unsuccessful checkpoint.  When the Function execution restarts again, the batch retrieved will have messages from the last known checkpoint.  Setting a very high value for maxBatchSize will also mean that you must re-process a large batch.  EventHub guarantees at-least-once delivery but not at-most-once delivery.  Azure Functions will not attempt to change that behavior.  If having only unique messages is a priority, you will need to handle de-duplication in your downstream workflows.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ling. Very helpful.

Comment: Why did you strike-out the part about uncaught exceptions causing unsuccessful checkpoint? If there is an exception thrown - does this mean that the message batch is simply discarded?

Comment: Kuba, yes. We recommend that customers handle the exception themselves.

Comment: So if an AF depends on some temporarily-down service (i.e. database) there is no straightforward way to *redo* the message?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I need to ask another question and not expect unrelated answer in comments .:)

Comment: You are correct. You should have a try-catch block that handles all exceptions. This is to prevent your Function from processing the same batch indefinitely in case there is an issue with the code itself.

Comment: I must admit I could not find reliable documentation on AF behaviour when an exception is thrown. Why is that not the case with ServiceBus (where message is delivered until `MaxDeliveryCount` exhausts IIRC)?

Comment: Can't speak for ServiceBus but AF's scaling logic will scale instances when messages pile up. If customer's Function code or downstream dependencies causes errors and AF stalls checkpointing indefinitely until customer fixes the issue, AF is unnecessarily spinning up instances that will never make any progress.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable support. Last question: any hint towards best practice in such scenario: My AF is EH-triggered, but I cannot reliably handle exception (database is not available). I don't want my message to get lost. What should I do not to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Encapsulate your Function processing code in a try-catch block and write the  message that could not be processed to another message broker,  e.g ServuceBus, EventHub, storage queue.  Handle those messages out-of-band or if it's a known common use-case, create another Function to handle those messages.

Answer (score 3):

By default it's going to be 1 by 1 processing, but you can do batches too. Change the signature of your function to

```
public static async Task Run(TraceWriter log, string[] eventHubMessages)
```

(if you change the name like I did, rename the binding parameter too)

Reference [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1029).